# Uploading 4 to 6 images, server time out in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Uploading 4 to 6 images, server time out in codeigniter
using jquery. I am uploading 6 images after cropping but,  getting server time out

Comment: _"server time out in codeignitor using jquery"_ ? Aah..What ???

Comment: php max execution time is 30 sec after that it throws error u may use this in the controller ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes